# How to get CNAME for Host name/ip adress

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have been able to get ip addresses from host name and vice versa using CFHost class but not able to get CNAME from Host name.

Anybody having any idea how to resolve the host name to get its CNAME.

Comment: You can't easily get CNAME records; there is no "reverse" record that points to CNAMEs from a A record

Comment: @Paulw11 I found the solution using DNSService .

Comment: @VarunMehta Either post a proper, full answer showing your solution or delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution for it. Hope it may help someone looking for it:

```
+ (void) getCNAME {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    DNSServiceRef serviceRef;

    DNSServiceErrorType error;

    error = DNSServiceQueryRecord(&serviceRef, 0, 0, "apple.com", kDNSServiceType_CNAME,

                                  kDNSServiceClass_IN, queryCallback, NULL);

    if (error != kDNSServiceErr_NoError){

        NSLog(@"DNS Service error");

    }



    DNSServiceProcessResult(serviceRef);

    DNSServiceRefDeallocate(serviceRef);

});}

static void queryCallback(DNSServiceRef sdRef,

                      DNSServiceFlags flags,

                      uint32_t interfaceIndex,

                      DNSServiceErrorType errorCode,

                      const char *fullname,

                      uint16_t rrtype,

                      uint16_t rrclass,

                      uint16_t rdlen,

                      const void *rdata,

                      uint32_t ttl,

                      void *context) {



if (errorCode == kDNSServiceErr_NoError && rdlen > 1) {

    NSMutableData *txtData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:rdlen];



    for (uint16_t i = 1; i < rdlen; i += 256) {

        [txtData appendBytes:rdata + i length:MIN(rdlen - i, 255)];

    }



    NSString *theTXT = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:txtData.bytes length:txtData.length encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"CNAME: %@", theTXT);

}}
```